# Referencing external objects as Django Models

Tags: python, django, model, mpd

I'm investigating writing a Django app that backs on to [MPD](http://www.musicpd.org) and it's accompanying client (MPC) to browse and play songs, manage playlists etc.

Much of the data that MPD stores (in memory) is available via the MPC commands, which there's an [existing Python library](https://pythonhosted.org/python-mpd2/topics/commands.html) for. However, since this data is already stored there would be no need to create 'traditional' Django models for Songs/Artists/Albums with a locally stored database.

I can't seem to find a way in the Django documentation to have models created from a list provided by an external data source (not a database as such).

There's a number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524214/how-to-externally-populate-a-django-model) about filling a Django model's table with data from external sources, but nothing about doing this on the fly, calling functions to get data from them.