# Can I make Django "greenlet-safe"?

Tags: database, django, django-models, concurrency, eventlet

The big picture is:
  I want to use eventlet in some application that does asynchronous IO while working with Django models externally. Working with Django externally is simple (see [Django: How can I use my model classes to interact with my database from outside Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383073/django-how-can-i-use-my-model-classes-to-interact-with-my-database-from-outside/383089#383089)) but it's not the main problem.

I presume (I haven't tested) that using Django from greenlets is dangerous. Actually, in the case of psycopg2, we have this warning (see http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#support-to-coroutine-libraries):

> Psycopg connections are not green
>   thread safe and can’t be used
>   concurrently by different green
>   threads

In Django there is one db connection per thread (right?) and as such it may lead to scary scenarios when used. Is it possible to provide a connection object manually somehow? Or make it "greenlet-local"?

My motivation is to use connection pool from eventlet (http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/db_pool.html) so that I could speed up my IO-bound application.

Answer (score 8):

There are some projects out there to make Django work well with greenlet. I would check out  [psycogreen](https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/src) which uses the coroutines support in Psycopg >= 2.2. There is a good blog post on using gevent, gunicorn, and psycogreen together with Django: http://dbinit.com/blog/going-green/.

Comment: This is very helpful, but it does not answer my question precisely. After some reading and digging I'm pretty much convinced I can use Django from eventlet without any problem. The only thing to do is to run "eventlet.monkey_patch()" which will change threading.local (and other system libraries) and therefore connections will become "greenlet-local" instead of "thread-local". Additionally eventlet patches psycopg2 so everything should run smoothly.

Comment: Perhaps I misread this question. If your goal of using eventlet is for  connection pooling why not use pgpool or pgbouncer?

Comment: I use eventlet to do some web-scraping stuff and I'm putting these data to database with Django models. Therefore I was curious if connections are "greenlet-safe" so that concurrent greenthreads won't run into each other. They are after monkey-patching. Also, after that, DB operations are concurrent as well.