# Can I make a field in database use this django code ,and don't use 'python manage.py startapp xx'

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure you can - just make the folder structure that `startapp` does and put that code in your models.py. Tell me why you want to, and I might be able to be more helpful!

Comment: can i make a field don't 'make the folder structure that startapp'

Comment: This question is quite confusing, but is this possibly a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182229/  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to access a database from Python, I recommend you use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead.